# To or without to

Tags: grammar, grammaticality-in-context

Should "to" be there if the full sentence is "Nobody else takes this seriously"

> Nobody else, though, seemed ***to*** take this seriously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Nobody else, though, seemed to take this seriously"

"Seems" requires a to-infinitival complement. So the "to" in this sentence is obligatory. Some verbs don't require "to" such as "help" and "make", but "seem" obligatorily takes a verb phrase preceded by "to".

Comment: That is to say, my sentence is incorrect, it should be "Nobody else seemed to take this seriously though" right?

Comment: "Nobody else, though, seemed to take this seriously" is OK. But you can't omit "to".